# Robolectric 3.0 , failed to test a function which starts a HandlerThread

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I have a simple class `Job` which extends [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html):

```
public class Job extends HandlerThread{
  public Job(String name) {
     super(name);
  }
  ...
}
```

Then, I have a `JobUtils` class which has a function to get a `Job` & `start()` it:

```
public JobUtils {
   public JobUtils() {
   }

   // I unit test this function in my test class below
   public Job getAndStartJob(String name) {
      Job job = new Job(name);
      job.start();
   }
}
```

I use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) 3.0 in my unit test, I test `JobUtils` class’ `getAndStartJob(String name)` function :

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class TestJobUtils{
 @Test
 public void testGetAndStartJob() {
    JobUtils jobUtils = new JobUtils();

    // error here
    jobUtils.getAndStartJob(“test-job”);
    …
 }
}
```

When I run my unit test code, I got the error

```
Exception in thread "test-job” java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.getMainLooper(ShadowLooper.java:70)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.doLoop(ShadowLooper.java:85)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.loop(ShadowLooper.java:76)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

It looks like Robolectric is not able to start the `HandlerThread` (the `job` instace in my code), or do I miss something? How to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue, not sure if your reason is the same because I used `RobolectricGradleTestRunner` and you have not posted whole test method body.
In my case it turns out that Robolectric's application (`RuntimeEnvironment.application`) is set to `null` (source of NPE) before `HandlerThread` starts executing because test method reaches the end earlier.

Workaround is to wait for all scheduled runnables at the end of test method:

```
    Robolectric.flushBackgroundThreadScheduler();
    Robolectric.flushForegroundThreadScheduler();
```